# Avoid manually insert device code key in AzureKusto

Tags: r, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to connect to db in Azure Data Explorer from R using *AzureKusto* library. Following this documentation https://github.com/Azure/AzureKusto, after calling *kusto_database_endpoint(...)* function I need to open a browser page and insert the printed code manually. There's a way to skip this manual step and do it automatically? Or there are alternatives for connecting to ADX db?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Co-creator of the package here. Thank you for the question. Yes, you can use the `get_kusto_token` function to obtain a token and then pass it to `kusto_database_endpoint` as the `.query_token` argument. `get_kusto_token` supports the following authentication flows:

- "authorization_code"
- "device_code"
- "client_credentials"
- "resource_owner"

For example, if you have an AAD application service principal that has access to the Azure Data Explorer cluster, you can use its ID and secret to authenticate:

```r
# authenticate using client_credentials method: see ?AzureAuth::get_azure_token
token <- get_kusto_token("https://mycluster.kusto.windows.net",
                         tenant="mytenant", 
                         authtype="client_credentials",
                         app="myappid", 
                         password="myclientsecret")

kusto_database_endpoint(server = "mycluster.kusto.windows.net",
                        database = "mydb", 
                        .query_token=token)
```

The help page `?AzureKusto::get_kusto_token` provides more detailed information on this. Also, please note that the `get_kusto_token` function is a wrapper around `AzureAuth::get_azure_token`. The readme for the AzureAuth R package has more detailed examples of other methods of obtaining an Azure access token: https://github.com/Azure/AzureAuth

Comment: Thanks Alex, now the code it's much more clear.